# where is word wrap in DBeaver 5.2.0?

Tags: dbeaver

I've been looking for hours in the options of DBeaver but I can't seem to find a "word wrap" option. Is it available, as [this changelog](https://dbeaver.io/2013/06/28/dbeaver-2-2-3/) suggests? I'm losing my patience over this issue...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Right click in the editor and go to `Format`>>`Toggle Word Wrap`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem came from the fact that I'm using DBeaver in my native language (French), and in fact "Word wrap" was badly translated! It's translated as something that would be like "soft word break" so I didn't think it was what I'm looking for.

Comment: "Soft Word Break" I would have been equally lost. o_0 Google Translate suggests "mot enveloppé" which seems reasonable.

Comment: trust Google Translate in 2018, and more so now in 2022, after all that data they must have from 4 years

Answer (score 0):

For those on Mac and Version 22.3.4:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So in DBeaver version 23.0.3 on Ubuntu:

[image]